# Rails and paperclip i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, paperclip

I use Rails 5.1.4 and paperclip. I have i18n website  http://example.com/en, http://example.com/de, http://example.com/uk.

How to serve file with different source (img src=?)file name depend on locale?

```
http://example.com/en/house.jpg
http://example.com/de/haus.jpg
http://example.com/uk/komnata.jpg
```

Is it possible with paperclip?
How to do it?

Regards
Ssebaaa

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for paperclip interpolations

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations

This is how you would use them.

In your model that utilizes paperclip, update the path to something of your choice:

```
has_attached_file :file,
                  .......
                  :path => ':locale/:style/:filename'
```

Then tell paperclip to look for the keyword, and what to replace it with

```
Paperclip.interpolates :locale do |attachment, style|
  attachment.some_logic_on_knowing_what_locale
end
```

(this part goes in paperclip.rb initializer)

Comment: OK, but in file system there is only file with name my_house.jpg. If i try serve file with name changed, it goes wrong. No file is displayed.